# iOS: When I switch from foreground to background I lose core data entities

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, core-data, icloud

I'm building an iPad in Swift app and I can't figure out how to keep my entities when I switch from foreground to background.
If I close the application (from the task manager) all the entities appears again. I'm using standard Core Data stack provided by Apple.
If I use iCloud this doesn't happen.

Any idea? I crawled StackOverflow but I can't find anything. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

App Delegate

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "it.b3lab.ProjectIceCream" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ProjectIceCream", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    //Add support to ligtweight migrations, and iCloud persistent storage
    var options = [
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: "ProjectIceCreamCloudStore"
    ]

    //enabled iCloud notiiccation subscription
    var notification = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notification.addObserver(self, selector: "storeDidChangeNotification:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,
        object:nil)
    notification.addObserver(self, selector: "storeWillChangeNotification:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification,
        object:nil)
    notification.addObserver(self, selector: "storeDidImportUbiquitousContent:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification,
        object:nil)

    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("ProjectIceCream.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType,
        configuration: nil, URL: url, options:options, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil

        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) 
    // This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()


//MARK: iCloud notification methods
func storeDidChangeNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Core Data successfully created and configured an iCloud-enabled persistent store")
    //TODO: controllare che i dati in ingresso siano validi
    //TODO: Implement Refresh your User Interface.
}

func storeWillChangeNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Called storeWillChangeNotification")
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!
    moc.performBlock { () -> Void in
        if moc.hasChanges {
            var saveError: NSError?
            if moc.save(&saveError) {
                print("iCloud save error \(saveError)")
            }
        }else{
            moc.reset()
        }
    }
    //TODO: Implement Refresh your User Interface.
}

func storeDidImportUbiquitousContent(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Called storeDidImportUbiquitousContent")
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!
    moc.performBlock { () -> Void in
        moc.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
}

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Example of fetch request

```
class func getReceipesFormCoreData() -> [Recipes] {
    let managedContext = getManagedObjectContext()
    let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Recipes",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!

    request.entity = entity
    var error: NSError?

    var results: [Recipes] = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
        as [Recipes]
    if (error != nil) {
        println("ERROR: Could not load \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    return results
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you entities are truly gone? It seems as if your code is just fetching them incorrectly if they appear again after the app is terminated...

Comment: How can I start to debug that? When I start the app the fetch method returns all the entities, but when I resume it from background the fetch methods returns 0 objects

Comment: I'd recommend posting your code and showing exactly where you're running it in your app's lifecycle.

Comment: I agree, some code would make the point more clear

Comment: Check that your managedObjectContext is not getting changed when you switch to background and back to foreground.  Your code does not show what you are doing when you switch to and from background.

Answer (score 0):

Are you triggering `saveContext()`?
If not, try calling at `func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)` on `AppDelegate`.
Also, you can call it right after your `CoreData` objects have been created.